# How to make QRCode Scanner Camera full screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, qr-code, react-qr-code

can someone help me to make my QR Scanner full screen,
here my code :

```
const App = () => {
  const [scan,setScan] = useState(false)

  const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
  return !scan ? (
    <View style={styles.falsecontainer}>
      <Pressable onPress={()=>setScan(true)}>
        <Text style={styles.startButton}>Start Scan</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  ):(
    <View style={styles.truecontainer}>
      <QRCodeScanner
      cameraStyle={[{height:SCREEN_HEIGHT}]}

      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

[image]result of my code,

Thanks for helping me

I tried many ways to make my QR code scanner fullscreen, but i didn't work, please help me

Comment: did you tried containerStyle and cameraContainerStyle?

Comment: yeah i have tried using that, but still same

Comment: Try using the below snippet. Posted in the answers section.

Answer (score 2):

Might be something wrong with the styles (truecontainer) you have given.

below code renders the camera in fullscreen mode.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
    <QRCodeScanner
       cameraStyle={{ height: height, width: width }}
    />
</View>
```